# Restlet - safely (thread wise) passing information from Filter to Resource

Tags: java, restlet

I would like to pass (additional) information from a Filter to a Resource.
The way I try to do it currently is, in the **Filter**:

```
getContext().getAttributes().put("additionalInformation", "info..");
```

and retrieve it in the **Resource**:

```
getContext().getAttributes().get("additionalInformation");
```

Questions:

1. Is this the best way to pass data from filter to resource?
2. Is this way Thread safe - if two clients will approach the same resource, will they both use the **same Context**?
3. How about using `request.getAttributes().put(...)` **instead** of `getContext().getAttributes().put(...)` ? what are the pros and cons?

**Context documentation:**

```
Concurrency note: attributes and parameters of a context are stored in
concurrent collections that guarantee thread safe access and modification. 
If several threads concurrently access objects and modify these collections,
they should synchronize on the lock of the Context instance.
```

Does it mean that the context is **NOT** thread safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the request object is the solution provided by Restlet to exchange data between all elements involved in the request handling using its attributes. This can be seen as a context for the request (and it's made for this) and such approach is indeed threadsafe.

The context is something shared by all elements within an application. The context within all elements involved in the request handling (filter, server resource, ...) is generally the one of the application. It's not thread safe and shouldn't be used to share data between elements within request.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks. Is there any difference using `getContext()` and `Context.getCurrent` ?

Comment: I would use the method `getContext` rather than `Context.getCurrent` as stated in the javadocs. The first one corresponds to the public API and lets Restlet provide the context for you.

Comment: I understand the logic, but `Context.getCurrent` provides me some thread safety, while I do not see how `getContext()` provides it...

Comment: TT, take a look at my third question, what do you think of it?

Comment: Hi Igor! I had a discussion with Thierry Boileau (http://stackoverflow.com/users/1921839/thierry-boileau) and updated my answer. Context mustn't be used to share data between elements within request. It's not made for that and not thread safe...